# Tool Bars Get stuck behind Avalon Dock

Tags: wpf, toolbar, avalondock

Im new to WPF and started using Avalon Dock. I have problem with Toolbar. When i drag toolbar in toolbar tray Tray gets expanded down and stuck behind Avalon Dock container.. How do i make it to re-size Automatically down so that Tool bars wont stuck behind?? Here is my XAML.. Thanks:)

```
<Window x:Class="PSWPF0._001.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:avalonDock="http://avalondock.codeplex.com"
    Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="381" d:DesignWidth="754" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding}" AllowDrop="True" ClipToBounds="True" IsItemsHost="False">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,0,0,0" Name="dockPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />


    <Menu Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,0,-2,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New" Click="MenuItem_Click_4">
                <MenuItem Header="Project" />
                <MenuItem Header="C Source File" />
                <MenuItem Header="Text File" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="MenuItem_Click_5"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="Undo" />
            <MenuItem Header="Redo" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" />
            <MenuItem Header="Cut" />
            <MenuItem Header="Paste" />
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Find" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="View" Click="MenuItem_Click_1">
            <MenuItem Header="Project Dashboard"/>

            <MenuItem Header="Project Explorer" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Help" Click="MenuItem_Click">
            <MenuItem Header="About" Click="MenuItem_Click_3"/>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Help" Header="Help Content" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>



    <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Background="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,23,-2,0">
        <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
            <Button>New</Button>
            <Button>Open</Button>
            <Button>Exit</Button>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar BandIndex="2" Band="2">
            <Button>Undo</Button>
            <Button>Redo</Button>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="2">
            <Button>Paint</Button>
            <Button>Spaell</Button>
            <Separator />
            <Button>Cut</Button>
            <Button>Copy</Button>
            <Button>Paste</Button>
            <Separator />
            <Button>Find</Button>
            <Button>Replace</Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>


    <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager" Margin="0,52,0,28" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Grid.Column="0" AllowMixedOrientation="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False" UseLayoutRounding="True">
        <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>     

            <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup DockMinHeight="70">
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Doc1">
                            <TextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutDocument Title="Doc2">
                            <TextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane >

                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>

                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup IsMaximized="True" DockMinHeight="70" DockHeight="250">
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Output">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Error List">
                            <TextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>

                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>


               </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>



            <avalonDock:LayoutRoot.RightSide>
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Properties" AutoHideMinWidth="200">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Project Explorer" AutoHideMinWidth="200">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="File Explorer" AutoHideMinWidth="200">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>

                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot.RightSide>



            <avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>

                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Project Dashboard" AutoHideMinWidth="200">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Hardware Toolbox" IsMaximized="True" CanAutoHide="True" IsActive="True" AutoHideMinWidth="200">
                            <ListBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>

                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Logic Building Blocks" AutoHideMinWidth="200">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>                        


                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>                
        </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager>




    <StatusBar Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,322,0,0" Name="statusBar1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use a dynamic layout like this:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>//<-- for menu
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>//<-- for toolbar
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>//<-- for docking manager
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>//<-- for status bar
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Always use Auto or Start grid lengths for dynamic layout arrangements of children controls,

Ado

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it took me a while to figure this out too (AD 2.0 on WPF with .NET 4.5) so I'll post for others who might be using this as a source. The answer from adospace works. However, you'll have to alter your code as well.

Eliminate the top margin from the DockingManager, unless you have another need for it. My layout looked so weird until I realized I still had a top margin set before using the grid's `RowDefinitions`. Also, remove the `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` from your menu unless you've got something else going on there. I don't have `VerticalAlignment` set either.

Here's what I've got that works just fine, including with the multiple bands. Using one of the AD test apps, it already has that root grid (gdlayoutRoot), so you can use that one.

```
<Grid Name="gdlayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Name="menuMain" Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" Name="New" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Name="Edit" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Document" Name="Document">
            <MenuItem Header="Import From _XML">
                <MenuItem Header="Entity" Name="ImportFromXML"  Click="ImportFromXML_Click" />
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="1">
        <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="0">
            <Button Content="Stuff"/>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <ad:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager" Grid.Row="3">
```